# Should I use SMALLINT instead of DATETIME in MySQL to save space?

Tags: mysql, datetime, size

I'm trying to decide whether to use SMALLINT(4) vs DATETIME to represent a year in MYSQL.

My table needs to have the model year, but I don't want to waste space with month or date like this: `20xx-01-01 00:00:00`.

So I could save space representing a year like this:

```
year SMALLINT(4);
```

If it's not a big savings, I'm fine using DATETIME.  If using 4 digit year is good for saving space, then how do I `$_POST` a four-digit year as a DATETIME?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is year data type in MySQL - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/year.html

> The YEAR type is a 1-byte type used to represent year values. It can be declared as YEAR(4) or YEAR(2) to specify a display width of four or two characters. The default is four characters if no width is given.

NOTE:

> The YEAR(2) data type has certain issues that you should consider before choosing to use it. As of MySQL 5.1.65, YEAR(2) is deprecated.

Possible range : 1901 to 2155, or 0000

Answer (score 1):

You'd use `mktime(date(Y), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATE data type (uses 3 bytes) instead of DATETIME (8 bytes).  You still have to store the month and day, but you don't need to store the time.

Comment: function getLocalDate($dateFormat,$timeZone)
{
 $timezone = new DateTimeZone($timeZone);
 $date = new DateTime();
 $date->setTimezone($timezone );
 return $date->format( $dateFormat );
}

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need the current year, just the year the product was produced. I'm still going to try and figure out the meaning of all that. I've just started PHP.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL DATE type allocates 3 bytes, while SMALLINT is 2-byte integer. So, it's eager savings, if any. On the other hand, every time you want to compare year-as-integer column with other date column, you need to do an extra work.

To convert integer input value to MySQL date you can use something like this:

```
$year = isset($_POST['year']) ? intval($_POST['year']) : 1970;
// ISO 8601 standard date representation is YYYY-MM-DD
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `mytable`(`datefield`) VALUES('{$year}-01-01')");
```

Comment: @Eric, please don't *completely rewrite* answers like that.  It's one thing to clean up wording and grammar, it's another thing entirely to put words in someone's mouth.  Consider adding your own answer instead.